# Upgrading Realm from "0.86.0" to "2.1.0"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, realm

I've use Realm in My Simple Application,

My Previous Version of Realm was **0.86.0** , to I'm planning to Upgrade it to latest version which is **2.1.0**

I was Creating RealmProxy To Dealing with all operations of realm Like This

```
  package devs.lo.fff.utils;

import android.content.Context;

import java.io.Closeable;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import io.realm.Realm;
import io.realm.RealmConfiguration;
import io.realm.RealmObject;
import io.realm.RealmQuery;
import io.realm.RealmResults;
import io.realm.exceptions.RealmException;

public class RealmProxy implements Closeable {

    private Realm realm;
    private WeakReference<Context> contextWeakReference;

    private static ThreadLocal<Set<RealmProxy>> realmsCache = new ThreadLocal<Set<RealmProxy>>() {
        @Override
        protected Set<RealmProxy> initialValue() {
            return new HashSet<>();
        }
    };

    private static final Object mLock = new Object();

    public RealmProxy(Context context) {
        contextWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(context);
    }

    public <T extends RealmObject> RealmQuery<T> where(Class<T> clazz) {
        checkRealm();
        if (!isValid()) {
            return null;
        }
        return realm.where(clazz);
    }

    public <T extends RealmObject> RealmResults<T> allObjects(Class<T> clazz) {
        checkRealm();
        if (!isValid()) {
            return null;
        }
        return realm.where(clazz).findAll();
    }

    public <T extends RealmObject> T createObject(Class<T> clazz) {
        if (!isValid()) {
            return null;
        }
        return realm.createObject(clazz);
    }

    public <T extends RealmObject> T copyToRealm(T object) {
        if (!isValid()) {
            return null;
        }
        return realm.copyToRealm(object);
    }

    public <T extends RealmObject> T copyToRealmOrUpdate(T object) {
        if (!isValid()) {
            return null;
        }
        return realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(object);

    }

    public <E extends RealmObject> List<E> copyToRealm(Iterable<E> objects) {
        if (!isValid()) {
            return null;
        }
        return realm.copyToRealm(objects);
    }

    public <E extends RealmObject> List<E> copyToRealmOrUpdate(Iterable<E> objects) {
        if (!isValid()) {
            return null;
        }
        return realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(objects);
    }

    public <E extends RealmObject> void save(final E object) {
        executeTransaction(new Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(RealmProxy realm) {
                copyToRealmOrUpdate(object);
            }
        });
    }

    public <E extends RealmObject> void save(final Iterable<E> objects) {
        executeTransaction(new Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(RealmProxy realm) {
                copyToRealmOrUpdate(objects);
            }
        });
    }

    //region experimental
    public <T extends RealmObject> RealmProxy set(T object, String fieldName, Object value) {
        Method method = findMethod(object, fieldName, value.getClass());
        invokeMethod(method, object, value);

        return this;
    }

    public <T extends RealmObject> RealmProxy set(T object, String fieldName, boolean value) {
        Method method = findMethod(object, fieldName, boolean.class);
        invokeMethod(method, object, value);

        return this;
    }

    public <T extends RealmObject> RealmProxy set(T object, String fieldName, long value) {
        Method method = findMethod(object, fieldName, long.class);
        invokeMethod(method, object, value);

        return this;
    }

    public <T extends RealmObject> RealmProxy set(T object, String fieldName, float value) {
        Method method = findMethod(object, fieldName, float.class);
        invokeMethod(method, object, value);

        return this;
    }

    public <T extends RealmObject> RealmProxy set(List<T> objects, String fieldName, Object value) {
        if (objects.isEmpty()) {
            return this;
        }

        Method method = findMethod(objects, fieldName, value.getClass());
        invokeMethod(method, objects, value);

        return this;
    }

    public <T extends RealmObject> RealmProxy set(List<T> objects, String fieldName, boolean value) {
        if (objects.isEmpty()) {
            return this;
        }

        Method method = findMethod(objects, fieldName, boolean.class);
        invokeMethod(method, objects, value);

        return this;
    }

    public <T extends RealmObject> RealmProxy set(List<T> objects, String fieldName, long value) {
        Method method = findMethod(objects, fieldName, long.class);
        invokeMethod(method, objects, value);

        return this;
    }

    public <T extends RealmObject> RealmProxy set(List<T> objects, String fieldName, float value) {
        Method method = findMethod(objects, fieldName, float.class);
        invokeMethod(method, objects, value);

        return this;
    }

    private <T extends RealmObject> void invokeMethod(Method method, T object, Object value) {

        synchronized (mLock) {
            internalBeginTransaction(false);
            try {
                method.invoke(object, value);
                internalCommitTransaction();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                internalCancelTransaction();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                internalCancelTransaction();
            }
        }

    }

    private <T extends RealmObject> void invokeMethod(Method method, List<T> objects, Object value) {

        synchronized (mLock) {
            internalBeginTransaction(false);
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
                    method.invoke(objects.get(i), value);
                }
                internalCommitTransaction();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                internalCancelTransaction();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                internalCancelTransaction();
            }
        }
    }


    private synchronized Method findMethod(Object obj,
                                           String property, Class paramType) {
        Class<?> theClass = obj.getClass();
        String setter = String.format("set%C%s",
                property.charAt(0), property.substring(1));
        //Class paramType = value.getClass();

        try {
            return theClass.getMethod(setter, paramType);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

    private synchronized Method findMethod(List objects,
                                           String property, Class paramType) {
        return findMethod(objects.get(0), property, paramType);
    }

    //endregion

    public <T extends RealmObject> void removeFromRealm(T object) {
        checkRealm();

        synchronized (mLock) {
            internalBeginTransaction(false);
            try {
                if (object.isValid()) {
                    object.deleteFromRealm();
                    internalCommitTransaction();
                }
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                internalCancelTransaction();
                throw new RealmException("Error during transaction.", e);
            } catch (Error e) {
                internalCancelTransaction();
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }

    public void beginTransaction() {
        beginTransaction(false);
    }

    public void beginTransaction(boolean commitCurrent) {
        synchronized (mLock) {
            internalBeginTransaction(commitCurrent);
        }
    }

    private void internalBeginTransaction(boolean commitCurrent) {
        checkRealm();

        if (realm.isInTransaction() && commitCurrent) {
            realm.commitTransaction();
            realm.beginTransaction();
        } else if (!realm.isInTransaction()) {
            realm.beginTransaction();
        }

    }

    public void commitTransaction() {
        synchronized (mLock) {
            internalCommitTransaction();
        }
    }

    private void internalCommitTransaction() {
        //checkRealm();
        if (isValid() && realm.isInTransaction()) {
            realm.commitTransaction();
        }
    }

    public void cancelTransaction() {
        synchronized (mLock) {
            //checkRealm();
            internalCancelTransaction();
        }
    }

    private void internalCancelTransaction() {
        //checkRealm();
        if (isValid() && realm.isInTransaction()) {
            realm.cancelTransaction();
        }
    }

    public void clear(Class<? extends RealmObject> classSpec, boolean autoTransaction) {
        if (autoTransaction) {
            beginTransaction();
            realm.delete(classSpec);
            commitTransaction();
        } else {
            realm.delete(classSpec);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        internalClose();
        realmsCache.get().remove(this);
    }

    private void internalClose() {
        if (realm != null) {
            realm.close();
            realm = null;
        }
    }

    private void checkRealm() {
        if (!isValid()) {

            Context context = contextWeakReference.get();

            if (context == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Context is null, Activity or Fragment is already killed");
            }

            RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context)
                    .name(Realm.DEFAULT_REALM_NAME)
                    .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                    .build();

            realm = Realm.getInstance(config);

            realmsCache.get().add(this);
        }
    }

    public boolean isValid() {
        return !(realm == null || realm.isClosed());
    }

    public <T extends RealmObject> void executeTransaction(T object, AdvancedTransaction<T> transaction) {
        checkRealm();

        synchronized (mLock) {
            internalBeginTransaction(false);
            try {
                if (object.isValid()) {
                    transaction.execute(object);
                    internalCommitTransaction();
                }
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                internalCancelTransaction();
                throw new RealmException("Error during transaction.", e);
            } catch (Error e) {
                internalCancelTransaction();
                throw e;
            }
        }

    }

    public void executeTransaction(Transaction transaction) {
        executeTransaction(transaction, false, false, null);
    }

    public void executeTransaction(Transaction transaction, boolean commitCurrent) {
        executeTransaction(transaction, commitCurrent, false, null);
    }

    public void executeTransaction(Transaction transaction, boolean commitCurrent, boolean doInBackground) {
        executeTransaction(transaction, commitCurrent, doInBackground, null);

    }

    public synchronized void executeTransaction(final Transaction transaction, boolean commitCurrent, boolean doInBackground, Realm.Transaction.Callback callbacks) {
        if (transaction == null || !isValid()) {
            return;
        }

        checkRealm();
        if (doInBackground) {
            realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(final Realm realm) {
                    transaction.execute(RealmProxy.this);
                }
            }, callbacks);
        } else {
            synchronized (mLock) {
                internalBeginTransaction(commitCurrent);
                try {
                    transaction.execute(this);
                    internalCommitTransaction();
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    internalCancelTransaction();
                    throw new RealmException("Error during transaction.", e);
                } catch (Error e) {
                    internalCancelTransaction();
                    throw e;
                }
            }


        }

    }

    public interface Transaction {
        void execute(RealmProxy realm);
    }

    public interface AdvancedTransaction<T extends RealmObject> {
        void execute(T object);
    }

    public void clearDataBase() {

        Context context = contextWeakReference.get();
        if (context == null) {
            return;
        }

        RealmConfiguration config;
        if (realm == null) {
            config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context)
                    .name(Realm.DEFAULT_REALM_NAME)
                    .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                    .build();
        } else {
            config = realm.getConfiguration();
        }

        /** all realm instances must be closed before deleting the file */
        for (RealmProxy realmProxy : realmsCache.get()) {
            realmProxy.internalClose();
        }
        /** clear threadLocal, its no longer needed*/
        realmsCache.remove();
        Realm.deleteRealm(config);

        /*File appDir = context.getExternalFilesDir("Documents");

        File[] files;
        if (appDir != null) {
            files = appDir.listFiles();
            if (files != null && files.length != 0) {
                for (File file : files) {
                    file.delete();
                }
            }
            appDir.delete();
        }*/

    }

    public static void clearDataBase(final Context context) {
        RealmProxy realm = new RealmProxy(context);

        realm.clearDataBase();
        realm.close();
    }

}
```

but after upgrading to 2.1.0 this file got some errors i'm trying to solve it, but it seems there are some errors, i don't know how to solve it

[image]

Please Advice

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

> 2.0.0
>
> Breaking Changes
>
> It is now required to call `Realm.init(Context)` before calling any other Realm API.
>
> `Removed RealmConfiguration.Builder(Context)`, `RealmConfiguration.Builder(Context, File)` and `RealmConfiguration.Builder(File)` constructors.
>
> 0.89.0
>
> Breaking changes
>
> `RealmChangeListener` provides the changed object/Realm/collection as well (#1594).
>
> 0.88.0
>
> Deprecated
>
> `Realm.executeTransaction(Transaction, Callback)`, and replaced it with
>
> - `Realm.executeTransactionAsync(Transaction)`,
> - `Realm.executeTransactionAsync(Transaction, OnSuccess)`,
> - `Realm.executeTransactionAsync(Transaction, OnError)`
> - `Realm.executeTransactionAsync(Transaction, OnSuccess, OnError)`.