# Cannot invoke method hasAnnotation() on null object

Tags: android, realm

I'm Just Trying to Upgrade Realm Database from 0.86 to 2.1 version.

but facing this Error Along With Android Studio

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithRealmTransformerForDebug'.
> Cannot invoke method hasAnnotation() on null object
```

**UPDATE (3)**

```
 clean assemble --stacktrace --info
    Starting Build
    Creating configuration compile                                               
    Creating configuration apk
    Creating configuration provided
    Creating configuration wearApp
    Creating configuration annotationProcessor
    Creating configuration androidTestCompile
    Creating configuration androidTestApk
    Creating configuration androidTestProvided
    Creating configuration androidTestWearApp
    Creating configuration androidTestAnnotationProcessor
    Creating configuration testCompile
    Creating configuration testApk
    Creating configuration testProvided
    Creating configuration testWearApp
    Creating configuration testAnnotationProcessor
    Creating configuration debugCompile
    Creating configuration debugApk
    Creating configuration debugProvided
    Creating configuration debugWearApp
    Creating configuration debugAnnotationProcessor
    Creating configuration testDebugCompile
    Creating configuration testDebugApk
    Creating configuration testDebugProvided
    Creating configuration testDebugWearApp
    Creating configuration testDebugAnnotationProcessor
    Creating configuration releaseCompile
    Creating configuration releaseApk
    Creating configuration releaseProvided
    Creating configuration releaseWearApp
    Creating configuration releaseAnnotationProcessor
    Creating configuration testReleaseCompile
    Creating configuration testReleaseApk
    Creating configuration testReleaseProvided
    Creating configuration testReleaseWearApp
    Creating configuration testReleaseAnnotationProcessor
    Parsing the SDK, no caching allowed
    Parsing D:\Android\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-23\package.xml
    Parsing D:\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\package.xml
    Parsing D:\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\package.xml
    Parsing D:\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.0-preview\package.xml
    Parsing D:\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.1\package.xml
    Parsing D:\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.3\package.xml
    Parsing D:\Android\sdk\build-tools\25.0.0\package.xml
    Parsing D:\Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\package.xml
    Parsing D:\Android\sdk\extras\android\support\package.xml
    Parsing D:\Android\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\package.xml
    Parsing D:\Android\sdk\extras\google\m2repository\package.xml
    Parsing D:\Android\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\package.xml


    * Exception is:
    org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithRealmTransformerForDebug'.
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:66)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
            at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
            at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
            at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
            at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
            at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
            at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
            at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
            at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
            at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
            at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
            at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
            at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
            at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
            at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:153)
            at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
            at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:150)
            at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
            at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
            at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
            at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
            at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
            at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:99)
            at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
            at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
            at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
            at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
            at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
            at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
            at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
            at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
            at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
            at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:173)
            at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:239)
            at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:212)
            at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
            at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
            at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
            at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
            at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:205)
            at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
            at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
            at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
            at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:55)
            at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:36)
            at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method hasAnnotation() on null object
            at io.realm.transformer.RealmTransformer$_transform_closure7.doCall(RealmTransformer.groovy:115)
            at io.realm.transformer.RealmTransformer.transform(RealmTransformer.groovy:112)
            at com.android.build.api.transform.Transform.transform(Transform.java:290)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:178)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:174)
            at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:156)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:173)
            at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:245)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:221)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:232)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
            ... 60 more


    BUILD FAILED

    Total time: 20.365 secs
    Stopped 0 compiler daemon(s).
```

Without any Reason this stopped the app to get running.

Any Solution for that ?

Comment: There's some kind of error with at least one of your Realm model classes. Wasn't there more to this error message?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce but i haven't change anything in my classes schema, it's was working from the previous version , do you mean that some annotations has been deprecated ?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce there is only this error message in the build

Comment: Did you clean then rebuild

Comment: @EpicPandaForce yes but nothing happens

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Could you please see the updated post

Comment: Do you by chance have any RealmObjects in a library project?

Comment: no, i always dealing with this especially with earlier version with Realm

Comment: Try running from the command with `./gradlew clean assemble --stacktrace`. It should report where exactly it is crashing

Comment: @EpicPandaForce **UPDATE (2)** has been added to the thread

Comment: @Loai this is a different error, you should set up your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to point at a **JDK** installation, and *not* a JRE installation.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce yeah i have solve that, but now the old error which is **hasAnnotation** has been throw, please check update 3

Comment: oh my god i've got it

Comment: @EpicPandaForce What is it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So according to your stack trace, [this line fails in the Realm-Transformer](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/realm-transformer/src/main/groovy/io/realm/transformer/RealmTransformer.groovy#L115):

> `def allModelClasses = allClassNames`
>
> `.findAll { it.endsWith('RealmProxy') }`
>
> `.collect { classPool.getCtClass(it).superclass }`
>
> **`.findAll { it.hasAnnotation(RealmClass.class) || it.superclass.hasAnnotation(RealmClass.class) }`**

So it says "if you have a class that ends with `RealmProxy`" which you [do as per this question where you literally have a class named `RealmProxy`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40256363/2413303), then it tries to get its superclass (which ought to be `RealmObject` or `RealmModel`) which it DOESN'T have because it's NOT part of the Realm schema, so it returns `null` and the transformer crashes.

**Solution 1:** rename your `RealmProxy` class to something like, `RealmFacade` or something

or

**Solution 2:** extend some random class with `RealmProxy` that doesn't have `@RealmClass` annotation.

```
public abstract class RealmProxyBase {
}

public class RealmProxy extends RealmProxyBase implements Closeable { 
   // ...
```

---

(in the meantime, I filed an issue for it [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3709))

Comment: Thank you very much my dear , what makes me sure that my code is ok that i have **RealmProxy** Before in previous version and it works fine without any problem, Any How thanks you and be ready to future Question :D

Comment: Well yes, but Realm added the Realm-Transformer in 0.88.0 and above, and no one else has run into this NPE before. Still, `solution 2` is rather simple, that is what i'd do.